# Get HTML content from tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm totally at a loss here. I want to get html content from tabs in Chrome.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test",is a test.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
  "background": {
      "scripts": ["main.js"],
      "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions": [
  "tabs",
  "https://www.google.com"
  ]
}
```

main.js

```
var timerObj = new Timer({'interval':5000});

chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(timerObj.start(mainF));

function mainF() {
    chrome.tabs.query( {} ,function (tabs) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        var url = tabs[i].url;
        if (url != null) {
             console.log(tabs[i].url);
             //I want to get html source here
        }
    }
  });
};

function Timer( obj ){
```

The last line `function Timer( obj ){` is truncated for brevity. `console.log(tabs[i].url);` is there for testing. For each tab, I wish to get the html source. With that source, I'll parse for tags and other content. I've seen other resources mentioning `sendMessage` and `onMessage`, but I'm not really getting it. Many other resources refer to the deprecated `sendRequest` and `onRequest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, there are three ways to implement this.

1. [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript). We can use [Programming Injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi) to inject content script into web page, in the callback we can get the returned value.
2. [Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). We can also inject content script in a way of `manifest.json`, then use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` and `chrome.runtime.onMessage` to transfer the data.
3. [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). Yes, this is also a way, we can directly make an ajax call in background page to get the source code of web page, because we could easily get the url. Obviously we need to start another http request compared with above two methods, but this is also a way.

In below sample code, I just use `browserAction` to trigger the event, then you can switch different methods to get the source code of web page by commenting out    other two methods and reserve only one.

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test is a test.",
    "version": "1.0",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "content.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "title"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "<all_urls>"
    ]
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {
    chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            var id = tabs[i].id;
            var url = tabs[i].url;
            //method1(id);
            method2(id);
            //method3(url);
        }
    });
});

function method1(tabId) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { "code": "document.documentElement.outerHTML;" }, function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
}

function method2(id) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(id, {action: "getSource"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response.sourceCode);
    });
}

function method3(url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    };
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.send();
}
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) { 
    if(request.action === "getSource") {
        sendResponse({sourceCode: document.documentElement.outerHTML});
    }
});
```

Comment: method 2 not working, I have "TypeError: Cannot read property 'sourceCode' of undefined"

Comment: Do it run on IE? I have a similar problem and I **must** use IE.

Comment: Good answer! Unfortunately manifest V2 will stop working soon. I guess I'd consider the answer as outdated